# Is it ok to post questions about Dreamboxes on SU?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Hi,

[Dreamboxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreambox) are Linux-powered TV receivers.

Is it ok to ask questions about them on SU? If not, where should I post them?

Answer (score 4):

Questions on Dreamboxes would be closed on SU for being off-topic, since Dreamboxes are

> a series of
>   Linux-powered DVB satellite,
>   terrestrial and cable digital
>   television receivers (set-top box)

You could ask questions about them on [Gadgets.Stackexchange](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/) I guess

Comment: Yeah I thought that too but it looks like the electronic gadges site is only about mobile phones. Anyway I will ask the question on its meta site once I have earned sufficient reputation.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Sathya, except for one thing. Dreamboxes run on a lightweight version of Linux and therefore, problems that directly concern that part of the Dreambox would fall under computer software, since this could help others that have similar questions about a linux system. If it's just about normal linux operations...

Comment: I can run Linux on older Playstation 3's. Does that make Linux questions on SU OK? :)

Comment: @Diago why wouldn't linux questions be ok? As long as it doesn't directly relate to your PS3... If it's just about normal linux operations.

Comment: Fair enough. If it's about a linux operation. If it's about linux and the actual device or running on it. No.

Comment: what you're saying makes sense to me. Similarly, I think a Dreambox developer should be able to ask questions about Python on stack overflow as long as they are not Dreambox-specific.

Comment: @reg I agree...